# Erro ao enviar dados via ksoap2 no webservice jboss

Tags: java, android, jboss

Então pessoal não estou conseguindo enviar os dados via ksoap2 no android. Aparece o seguinte erro:

[image: Erro ao enviar dados]

Eu sinceramente não entendi qual o problema, por isso recorri ao stack, pois o namespace esta certo e a ação tbm, segue o codigo em android:

```
   SoapObject soapObject = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,"inserirCoord");

    PropertyInfo infoPrest = new PropertyInfo();
    infoPrest.setName("idPrestador");
    infoPrest.setValue(idPrestador);
    infoPrest.setType(PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS);
    soapObject.addProperty(infoPrest);
    soapObject.addProperty("latitude",latitude);
    soapObject.addProperty("longitude",longitude);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);


    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.implicitTypes = true;
 //   envelope.encodingStyle = SoapSerializationEnvelope.XSD;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(soapObject);


   /* MarshalDouble md = new MarshalDouble();
    md.register(envelope);*/

    HttpTransportSE transportSE = new HttpTransportSE(transport);

    try
    {
        transportSE.call("inserirCoord",envelope);
        SoapObject resultado = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();

        return Boolean.parseBoolean(resultado.toString());
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
         erro = ex.toString();
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: ele está dando erro com o idPrestador, talvez ele não deveria receber como string? ou outro formato fora integer?
Seria estranho, mas é o que parece estar acontecendo

Comment: Não, o tipo de dado do idPrestador no webservice é int mesmo.

Comment: Estranho, por que pelo que deu para entender do erro, o problema está no idPrestador, e ele não está pedindo nenhuma classe específica nele

Comment: Realmente, parece que o erro é nesse parametros ai